# Cannot get JavaScript to connect to PostgresSql

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express

I making a small demo program to learn about web development.
So I just want to get some feedback from my database on A localhost server.
But for some reason, I cannot get a connection

I have tried following this guide:
https://blog.logrocket.com/setting-up-a-restful-api-with-node-js-and-postgresql-d96d6fc892d8

This is my queries.js:

```
const Pool = require('pg').Pool;
const pool = new Pool({
    user: 'barl',
    host: 'localhost',
    database: 'students',
    password: '123456',
    port: 5432,
});

const getUserById = (request, response) => {
    const id = parseInt(request.params.id);

    pool.query('SELECT * FROM students WHERE student_id = $1', [id], (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            throw error;
        }
        response.status(200).json(results.rows);
    })
};

module.exports = {
    getUserById
};
```

This is my server.js:

```
//Getting the express module
const express = require('express');
//Creating an App var that run the express method
const app = express();

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const db = require('./queries');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(
    bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: true,
    })
);

app.get('/students', function(req, res){
    db.getUserById;
});


//Setting the server to run on port blah blah
const server = app.listen(7000, () => {
    console.log(`Express running → PORT ${server.address().port}`);
});
```

And, package.json:

```
{
  "name": "untitled3",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "npx pm2 start server.js --watch"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^2.6.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "pg": "^7.10.0",
    "pm2": "^3.5.0",
    "body-parser": "latest"
  }
}
```

My postgres DB is running and working perfectly on my machine, And I can see the information.

But when I put this into the browser:

```
http://localhost:7000/students/1
```

I get:

```
Cannot GET /students/1
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you've not defined the route which you're trying to access from your browser:

You're trying to access `students/someid` which does not exist. Also you need to pass the `request` and `response` object

You can define one as:

```
app.get('/students/:id', function(req, res){
  db.getUserById(req, res);
});
```

`:id` is a `named parameter` which you can access through `req.params`

Your route is not doing any work aside from calling your exported db function, might as well simply mount it as:

```
app.get('/students/:id', db.getUserById)
```

Comment: First id like to say thank you, as it is working.
Secondly, I also tried this:
```
app.get('/students/:id', db.getUserById)
```
and it is also working. How is that possible? considering I am not sending and parameters to the db function

Comment: note when you do `app.get('/some, (req, res) => { res.send('hello') })` you're only defining a function as the second parameter (annonymous function), you're not actually invoking it. express does that for you. So it doesn't matter where you define, all you've to do is **mount** the middleware so express can access it. Hope it makes sense